# Express 4.17 req.body is being printed as buffer

Tags: express, request, buffer

Something that I wanted clarification on is when console.logging req.body in my express app. I end up with a buffer/string or hexadecimal of some sort when I'm expecting an JSON object. I'm using postman to send a raw json body.
Here are some visuals of the source code and terminal/postman results.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');

const app = express();
app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({strict: false}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

const posts = {};

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  res.send(posts);
});

app.post('/posts', (req, res) => {
  const id = randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
  const { title } = req.body;
  
  console.log(req.body)
  posts[id] = {
    id,
    title: title
  };

  res.status(201).send(posts[id]);
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on 4000');
});
```

[Console.log terminal of buffer/hex/string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvMgn.png)

[Postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yACo.png)

[Postman Raw String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS0U7.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  When code is part of your question, it should be pasted into your question as text, not as images.  This is for a whole bunch of good reasons: it can be search indexed, people answering can copy paste portions into their answers without having to retype, it's more accessible for those with vision issues, etc...  Please fix your question and paste the code into your question as text and format it appropriate as code.

Comment: Since you're new here, I've given you the courtesy of looking at your images and posting an answer.  Please fix this question to show your code as text and follow the proper procedure for future questions.

Comment: Please don't just post and disappear.  If you're not checking back multiple times in the first hour, you miss your best chance to engage with those who are trying to help.   As for me, I won't be online anymore for awhile so hopefully my answer will be sufficient as we missed our opportunity to discuss if anything in the answer isn't clear to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm checking the answer right now and fixing the post. I had fallen asleep upon posting since it was 12 a.m eastern time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));`  is going to give you a Buffer object and since that's your first middleware that might handle that mime type, that's what you're going to get for any `application/json` request.

Right from the [Express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.raw) for `express.raw()`:

> This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming
> request payloads into a Buffer

It's unclear why you're using `express.raw()` as that is not typical for JSON payloads, but when doing so, you are going to get a `Buffer` - that's how it works.  One would more typically use `express.json()` for JSON payloads and let it parse your JSON so that `req.body` contains an actual Javascript object.

If you remove the `app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));` line of code and let the `app.use(express.json());` line of code right after it handle the `application/json` payloads, then you will get your parsed data in `req.body`.

Keep in mind that when using middleware they are processed in the order declared and for this specific type of middleware, the first one that matches and reads the body from the incoming stream takes precedence and none of the others after it will be able to do their job (since the incoming stream has already been read).